# Is there a predicate that replaces every anonymous variable, by the number 1? On a list of only zeros and ones and anonymous variables

Tags: list, recursion, replace, prolog

I have a predicate called unify which should replace all the anonymous variables on a list (the list contains zeros, ones and anonymous variables) by the number one.
However I think I'm doing the recursion wrong, since the output isn't the list fully completed.
Here's the code:´

```
unify([P|T], [1|L]):-
    P\==0, P\==1, !, unify(T,L).
unify([P|T],[P|L]):-
    P==0; P==1,!, unify(T,L).
```

The output, for example, for the input `unify([_,_,1,0,0,_,_],L).` should be `L=[1,1,1,0,0,1,1].`

Comment: Where do you know that these variables are anonymous? Probably you mean all variables.

Comment: That's the problem, I think, I don't know how to distinguish the anonymous variables from the numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `unify/2` is usually used for actual general unification. Note that this predicate is not a pure relational one.

```
binlist_oneified(Bs, Os) :-
   must_be(list, Bs),
   copy_term(Bs, Os),
   term_variables(Os, Ws),
   maplist(=(1), Ws).
```

Comment: However, there's still no way to distinguish an anonymous variable from a named variable (after the term is read), correct?

Comment: @Dan: Of course not. It just looks for variables. So shared variables are one-ified as well. But I suspect that this is what is asked for since there are two arguments.

Comment: @FranciscoSaioteRodrigues note that you cannot distinguish anonymous variables from other variables. But you don't need to for this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @FranciscoSaioteRodrigues if this answer is acceptable to you, please click the check mark to "accept" it.